# How can I get MySQL data into Javascript using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I have setup a leaflet.js map. One is able to add markers to it like this:

```js
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map).bindPopup("hello world").openPopup();
```

I have a given number -- lets say 5 -- items in a MySQL database that each hold the values "lon", "lat", and "text". I want to add every item to the map like this:

```js
L.marker([LON, LAT]).addTo(map).bindPopup(TEXT).openPopup();
```

I tried multiple ways to get the MySQL data with AJAX, however all the examples I have seen displayed it into the DOM and none processed it in Javascript. Is there a way to draw each element onto the map with JS/jquery?

Comment: sure, either loop over the result with a foreach loop, or json_encode the data into a script tag and loop over it in js with a for loop, or make an ajax call to fetch json and loop over it in js, if you dont know how to loop or do ajax calls, check out the manuals

Comment: add a few of those multiple ways to your question and someone will probably figure out the problem.